Maintaining stacked PRs with constant amending
My employer requires that all pull requests contain a single commit. So I often have several inflight PRs that depend on each other. Given master -> branch A -> branch B, when I need to update A, I just git commit --amend && git push -f, and then switch to B and git pull --rebase origin A. However, this very often results in merge conflicts where I essentially have to redo the changes that i just made to A.
Can someone help me come up with a better workflow than this? My previous git experience has all been with multi-commit branches and merge commits, so this is a bit foreign to me. I know things like fixup+autosquash, --update-refs exist, but I can't find good resources on how to use them for this.
Thanks!

I think rebase with updateRefs is indeed the solution; I found this article to be helpful.

thanks @BenjaminW. I've read that article but it seems to apply/work only for adding commits to A, not for amending A's single commit.

If you are using a stacked workflow I encourage you to check out stgit. It doesn't solve the github integration, but it makes for a great local workflow.

I understand that if you amend A, you have to rebase B on that new A, and all other branches are then updated automatically.
